# Browser back button goes too far back in react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My react application has a form with 3 "pages" of inputs the user needs to fill out. All 3 "pages" are in 1 component and which page is shown depends on whether state.step equals 1,2 or 3 respectively.

This works great except when the user is on "page" 3 and hits the browser back button they don't get sent to "page" 2--they are sent away from the form all together and back to the dashboard.

How do I configure my app so that the browser back button will work with my "pages"? I'm using react router 3.

Comment: have u tried using seperate routes for each page!!!!

Comment: You could also add query params to control which page is shown. i.e. `?page=1`